# Role of underscore "_" in conditional statement (if else) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Can somebody please explain the role of "_" in Swift code below.

```
var guessWasMade: Bool {
    if let _ = game.guesses[currentQuestion] {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

I understand how it is usually used as unnamed parameter in for-loops and functions.
But could not find any explanation for if else statement.

Tutorial explains it as *guessWasMade checks game.guesses for a value. If a value is found we know the user has made a guess at the question.*

game.guesses is an array of integers.

This is part of class declaration. Full code looks like this

```
class GameViewModel: ObservableObject {

  // MARK: - Published properties
  // 2
  @Published private var game = Game()
 
  // MARK: - Internal properties
  // 3
  var currentQuestion: Question {
     game.currentQuestion
  }
  // 4
  var questionProgressText: String {
    "\(game.currentQuestionIndex + 1) / \(game.numberOfQuestions)"
  }

// 1
  var guessWasMade: Bool {
       if let _ = game.guesses[currentQuestion] {
           return true
       } else {
           return false
       }
   }

   // MARK: - Internal Methods
   // 2
   func makeGuess(atIndex index: Int) {
       game.makeGuessForCurrentQuestion(atIndex: index)
   }
   // 3
   func displayNextScreen() {
       game.updateGameStatus()
   }
}
```

Comment: It means that the result value is not interesting, only if it is nil or not. `let _ = …` in an `if` clause is no different than anywhere else

Comment: You can simply return one liner  `game.guesses[currentQuestion] != nil`

Comment: Please read [Wildcard Pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#ID420) in the Swift Language Guide

Comment: If tutorial has such a poorly written code, I suggest to... find another tutorial. Because really, `if let _ = game.guesses[currentQuestion] { return true }` would be ok for someone with about 2 weeks of swift experience. Otherwise, it's just ridiculous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`If let`](https://www.zerotoappstore.com/swift-if-let-explained.html) statements check to see if the value is nil. If it is, then the statement is false. If it isn't, then the value is assigned to a variable.

```swift
var optionalValue: Int? = 42

if let nonOptionalValue = optionalValue {
    print(nonOptionalValue) // -> 42
} else {
    print("optionalValue is nil")
}
```

So, when you do `if let _ = game.guesses[...]`, you are checking to see if `game.guesses[...]` is `nil`. If it isn't, then you are ignoring the value with a *[wildcard pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#ID420)* (`_`), which will match anything.

Because you are ignoring the value, it is the same as saying

```swift
if game.guesses[...] != nil {
    return true
} else {
    return false
}
```

Then, because you are simply returning the value of the condition, you can just return the condition itself:

```swift
var guessWasMade: Bool {
   game.guesses[currentQuestion] != nil
}
```